# SSRS - Run multiple dependent parameters from a SQL view. Save RS in memory

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have 3 parameters the user needs to select when displaying an SSRS report.  Each subsequent parameter is dependent on the previously selected parameter.  The result set comes from one SQL view.

When choosing the first parameter, the 2nd parameter set takes 10-15 seconds to populate.  The same occurs for the third parameter after choosing the 2nd parameter.  I'm guessing it is running the view every time.  How do I save the results in memory so the SQL view does not need to be hit every time to narrow the query dependent on the results?

For Example:
[image]

When **A** is selected for 1st parameter, only show **1** and **2** for the 2nd parameter choices and then show only **@** if the user selects **1** (for the 2nd parameter) in the 3rd parameter but without running the view every time a parameter is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset which populates the Available Values for Parameter 2, there should be a reference to Parameter 1. In other words, Parameter 1 should be in the SQL and show up in the Parameters tab for the dataset. Similarly, Parameters 1 and 2 should be in the dataset for Parameter 3. By doing this, the SQL for each subsequent dropdown should run more quickly. This is usually more efficient than using Filters on the datasets.

If you have it set up this way and it's still slow, it's not the report that's being slow, it's the query. It would be good to review your execution plans and consider adding indexes to allow the query to run efficiently with these parameters. Worst case, you may need to skip the view and select directly from the tables so that you get a better execution plan.

Alternatively, you can also try turning on caching. This allows the datasets to pull from memory rather than running the same SQL over and over. With this approach you would use dataset filters, not parameters as described above. Depending on how frequently the data is updated, this may be an option to help with the speed.

Comment: My report is setup in the manner you described, the parameters are in the query and not the filter.  Unfortunately, I am not the owner of the DB/table.

Comment: In that case, the caching alternative I mentioned may be your best option.